# Sonata admin - Sorting by translated property

Tags: sonata-admin, sonata, symfony4

I have a code:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('name')
   [..]
```

This is a property from translation (KNP translatable). I tried use:

- translations.name - label is sortable, but values are missing
- name or translate.name - label is not sortable, but values are ok

I don't have any idea how I should to do this. Maybe someone here can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `$listMapper->add('name',null, array('sortable'=>true))` ?

Comment: Yes, but I got "error: Argument 1 passed to Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Datagrid\ProxyQuery::entityJoin() must be of the type array, null given"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made it.

1) Create abstract admin class:

```
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin as BaseAbstractAdmin;

abstract class AbstractAdmin extends BaseAbstractAdmin { .. }
```

2) Use this class in your admin classes:

```
class UserAdmin extends AbstractAdmin { .. }
```

3) Add this to your column definition:

```
->add(
     'fieldName',
      null,
      [
          'sortable'                         => true,
          'sort_field_mapping'               => ['fieldName' => 'id'],
          'sort_parent_association_mappings' => [],
      ]
)
```

4) Add this method to your abstract admin class:

```
protected function prepareQueryForTranslatableColumns($query)
{
    $currentAlias     = $query->getRootAliases()[0];
    $locale           = $this->request->getLocale();
    $parameters       = $this->getFilterParameters();
    $sortBy           = $parameters['_sort_by'];
    $fieldDescription = $this->getListFieldDescription($sortBy);
    $mapping          = $fieldDescription->getAssociationMapping();
    $entityClass      = $mapping['targetEntity'] ?: $this->getClass();

    if ($mapping) {
        $mappings   = $fieldDescription->getParentAssociationMappings();
        $mappings[] = $mapping;

        foreach ($mappings as $parentMapping) {
            $fieldName = $parentMapping['fieldName'];
            $query->leftJoin($currentAlias . '.' . $fieldName, $fieldName);

            $currentAlias = $fieldName;
        }
    }

    $query
        ->leftJoin(
            $currentAlias . '.translations',
            'tr',
            'with',
            'tr.locale = :lang OR
                (NOT EXISTS(SELECT t.id FROM ' . $entityClass . 'Translation t WHERE t.translatable = tr.translatable AND t.locale = :lang)
                AND tr.locale = :lang_default)'
        )
        ->addOrderBy('tr.name', $parameters['_sort_order'])
        ->setParameter(':lang', $locale)
        ->setParameter(':lang_default', 'en');

    return $query;
}
```

I use JOIN to get translations for currently selected locale and, if translation doesn't exist yet for current locale, I add translation for default locale (it is a reason for use NOT EXIST).

5) Add this method to your admin class:

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
    $query = parent::createQuery($context);

    if ('list' === $context) {
        $parameters = $this->getFilterParameters();
        $sortBy     = $parameters['_sort_by'];

        if (in_array($sortBy, ['fieldName', 'fieldName.fieldName2', 'fieldName3', ..])) {
            $query = parent::prepareQueryForTranslatableColumns($query);
        }
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: I added a new better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but I was having the same problem.

The easiest solution for me was to set the right property mapping like this:

```
$listMapper->add(
    'translations', 
    null,
    [
        'sortable' => true,
        'associated_property' => 'name',
        'sort_field_mapping' => [
            'fieldName' => 'name',
        ],
        'sort_parent_association_mappings' => [
            ['fieldName' => 'translations'],
        ],
    ]
);
```